# How to animate expand / collapse UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, koloda

I'm building a tinder-like app, and I'm using a library KolodaView: https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

In the library they have functionality setup so when you tab the UIView it triggers an action. At the moment its setup to open up a URL. As seen below:

```
extension ViewController: KolodaViewDelegate {

func kolodaDidRunOutOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView) {
    print("Out of cards")
}

func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSelectCardAt index: Int) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://yalantis.com/")!)
}

func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAt index: Int, in direction: SwipeResultDirection) {

    let x = data[index]
    print("did swipe \(x) in diredtion: \(direction)")
}

}
```

How can I set this up so that when you tap on the UIView it expands / collapses and therefore showing more information. Basically working like an accordion. Preferably the information that is shown from the expanding UIView would come from XIB file view.

I already have the main UIView setup in my datasource from another XIB file view.

```
 extension ViewController: KolodaViewDataSource {

func kolodaNumberOfCards(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {

    let swipeView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SwipeView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! SwipeView
    let x = data[index]

    //        swipeView.setupView(job: x)


    return swipeView
}

func kolodaSpeedThatCardShouldDrag(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> DragSpeed {
    return .default
}

}
```

I am quite new to swift and any help would greatly appreciated.